# Understanding the use of command substitution in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to know what the difference between the two commands below is ?

```
ubuntu:~/bin$ (ls -A1 /home/ | wc -l) 
1

ubuntu:~/bin$ $(ls -A1 /home/ | wc -l)
1: command not found
```

If I put `dir_count=(ls -A1 /home/ | wc -l)` in a script i get the following error.

```
./two_args: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./two_args: line 24: `dir_1_count=(ls -A1 "$dir_1" | wc -l)'
```

where as the following works:

```
 dir_count=$(ls -A1 /home/ | wc -l)
```

Comment: You define a variable with `var=$(command)`. So you have to use `dir_count=$(ls -A1 /home/ | wc -l)`. No matter if it is a script or the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(command)`, is [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). It simply executes the command and substitutes the standard output of the command.

So if you want to set the variable, simply: `dir_count=$(ls -A1 /home/ | wc -l)`

About the rest of your code:

```
(ls -A1 /home/ | wc -l)
```

this one executes the command in a subshell. You probably don't want those parentheses.

```
$(ls -A1 /home/ | wc -l)
```

this one just doesn't make *any* sense, you substitute the result, so you get `1`, and the shell will try to execute the command called `1`.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the variable management in the script, I recommend you try the following:

```
dir_1_count=`ls -A1 ${dir1} | wc -l`
```

Use the character "`" to delimitate variables and store the result of a usual shell command in your script.

Remember to use the inverted apostrophe, not the single quote, copy the variable definition I just gave you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that does not answer my question. I'll try your method. However still looking for the answer.

Comment: this is the old style command substitution, and it's not recommanded (it's not wrong, but less flexible and harder to parse with the human eye)

Answer (score 0):

`(...)` is just a special grouping operator. It runs `...` in a subshell, meaning that it cannot modify the parent's execution environment (so, for example, `(foo=bar)` is useless, because the assignment will not survive past the end of the command), but is otherwise treated pretty normally (its standard output goes to standard output, etc.).

---

`$(...)` is a substitution; just like how `$foo` gets replaced with the value of the variable `foo`, `$(...)` gets replaced with the output of the command `...`. More precisely . . . like `(...)`, it also runs `...` in a subshell, but in addition, it captures the standard output of `...`, and then ends up getting replaced with that output. So, for example, this:

```
"$(echo cd)" "foo$(echo bar)"
```

runs `echo cd` and captures the `cd`, and runs `echo bar` and captures the `bar`, and then runs the combined command `cd foobar`.